# My js code doesnt work,from other pc,but run on well on the my main machine on IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, webserver, iis-6

I have a IIS 7 webservice. My problem is this - I can open the web page on the my main machine, something like 192.168.2.100/Login.aspx. However when I try to reach this machine from another machine, it shows nothing.

My page uses the EXTjs scripts. Any HTML shows but the javascript (ext.js) doent work. It worked last week, but I dont know what happened. What could be the possible problem here?

Comment: Have you used the browser script debugger & network monitor to check what's running & whether you can access all the files externally?

Comment: interesting but I solved problem .Problem is related to the time setting of Pc.aftering correct time of the Pc,everying works fine